# Terraform deployment of Fluent Bit which should direct specific namespaces' logs to separate Log Analytics workspaces

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, fluent-bit, azure-log-analytics-workspace

The overall idea should  generate Fluent Bit's output blocks for each namespace.
This will allow the logs of each namespace to be directed to a designated Log Analytics workspace, within a table, named as the namespace.

So... I have two maps with data - one is a simple key-value map (fluentbit_output_mappings), the other is a map of objects which contain map with more variables (log_analytics_workspaces).
The values of the first map equal to the object names of the second map (and to second map's log_analytics_name parameters values also).

With this relation, I would like to be able to pull each of the second map's objects resource_group_name parameter's value.

Once then, using data source [azurerm_log_analytics_workspace](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/log_analytics_workspace), I would like to get workspace_id and primary_shared_key of the Log Analytics workspaces.

Afterward, I would like to be enriching a template which should contain the key of the simple key-value map (fluentbit_output_mappings), and the workspace_id and primary_shared_key of the Log Analytics workspaces. The template should then be ready for an output, which I can use later.

Notes:

- The map of Log Analytics workspaces objects cannot be adjusted as it is used elsewhere
- Additional enhancements are also included like making sure the correct Log Analytics workspaces names are added as values in the fluentbit_output_mappings map; dependencies to avoid false runs

```
variable "log_analytics_workspaces" {
  type = map(
    object({
        "LA1" = {
        resource_group_name = "LA1_RG"
        log_analytics_name  = "LA1"
        log_analytics_sku   = "PerGB2018"
        },
        "LA2" = {
        resource_group_name = "LA2_RG"
        log_analytics_name  = "LA2"
        log_analytics_sku   = "PerGB2018"
        },
        "LA3" = {
        resource_group_name = "LA3_RG"
        log_analytics_name  = "LA3"
        log_analytics_sku   = "PerGB2018"
        },
        "LA4" = {
        resource_group_name = "LA4_RG"
        log_analytics_name  = "LA4"
        log_analytics_sku   = "PerGB2018"
        }
    })
  )
}

variable "fluentbit_output_mappings" {
  description = "Map of K8s namespaces to Log Analytics workspace names"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {
    # Add more mappings as needed. Syntax: K8s_namespace = Log_Analytics_workspace
    "ns1" = "LA1"
    "ns2" = "LA2"
    "ns3" = "LA3"
    "ns4" = "LA1"
    "ns5" = "LA2"
  }
}

data "log_analytics_workspace" "mappings" {
  for namespace, log_analytics_name in var.fluentbit_output_mappings : namespace => {
    namespace = namespace
    log_analytics_workspace_name = log_analytics_name == var.log_analytics_workspaces[log_analytics_name].log_analytics_name ? log_analytics_name : "falseValue"
    log_analytics_resource_group_name = var.log_analytics_workspaces[log_analytics_name].resource_group_name

    # Assert condition to stop processing if log_analytics_workspace_name is "falseValue"
    assert(log_analytics_workspace_name != "falseValue", "Error: log_analytics_workspace_name is invalud. Check terragrunt.hcl for correct mapping in fluentbit_output_mappings")
  }

  depends_on = [
    var.fluentbit_output_mappings,
    var.log_analytics_workspaces,
  ]
}

data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log_analytics" {
  for_each = { for namespace, log_analytics_name in var.fluentbit_output_mappings : namespace => log_analytics_name }
  
  name                = data.log_analytics_workspace.mappings[var.fluentbit_output_mappings[count.index]].log_analytics_workspace_name
  resource_group_name = data.log_analytics_workspace.mappings[var.fluentbit_output_mappings[count.index]].log_analytics_resource_group_name

  depends_on = [
    var.fluentbit_output_mappings,
    data.log_analytics_workspace.mappings,
  ]
}

data "template_file" "example" {
  count = length(var.workspace_mappings)

  template = <<YAML
[OUTPUT]
    Name azure
    Match kube.*${var.fluentbit_output_mappings.key}*
    Customer_ID ${data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics[data.log_analytics_workspace.mappings[var.fluentbit_output_mappings[count.index]]].workspace_id}
    Shared_Key ${data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics[data.log_analytics_workspace.mappings[var.fluentbit_output_mappings[count.index]]].primary_shared_key}
    Log_Type ${var.fluentbit_output_mappings.key}
  YAML

  depends_on = [
    var.fluentbit_output_mappings,
    data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspace,
  ]
}

output "rendered" {
  value = join("\n", data.template_file.example[*].rendered)
  sensitive = true
}
```

However, upon run, I receive the following error where the , (comma) between "namespace" and "log_analytics_name" on line 42* (in data.log_analytics_workspace.mappings):

- It is line 17 for me as log_analytics_workspaces is used from variables.tf and fluentbit_output_mappings is declared in the above .tf file

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid block definition
│
│   on fluentbit.tf line 42, in data "log_analytics_workspace" "mappings":
│   42:   for namespace, log_analytics_name in var.fluentbit_output_mappings : namespace => {
│
│ Either a quoted string block label or an opening brace ("{") is expected
│ here.
╵
time=2024-02-09T15:49:47Z level=error msg=1 error occurred:
        * exit status 1
```

Any ideas on how to work this out will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: To pull each of the second map's objects resource_group_name parameter's value, you can use the for_each meta-argument to iterate over the log_analytics_workspaces map and create a map of resource_group_name values.

Comment: Thanks, Arko, but that won't work easily as I have to use their instances afterward. Or at least I cannot think of a correct way so that things can be mapped. Would you try it and let me know, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as no answers and I was stuck, I decided to modify my map so that it includes the Log Analytics' resource group names. Once then, I had to only loop through a single loop and didn't have to bind values and variables from different map objects.
That then gave me a smooth way of operation to loop in order to generate the output.

I know there is a better way, but I will seek for it upon optimization as I do not have time for it now.